# Raspberry pi to laptop communication via Wifi using socket

Tags: sockets, raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi4

I am completely newbie for programming with RPI. I need to establish communication between my laptop and RPI via wifi. I have connected my RPI with the same wifi network as my laptop. I am thinking of using socket programming. I have 1 client-server and python server code:

client:

```
import socket               
s = socket.socket()        
host = ''# ip of raspberry pi 
port = 12345               
s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

python:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = '' #ip of raspberry pi
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print ('Got connection from',addr)
  c.send('Thank you for connecting')
  c.close()
```

My question is which compiler do I need to use for this code in both laptop & RPI? Also, is the above code and creating a server with socket programming a good idea?
please advise.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you are trying to do. Are you trying to transfer files once a week? The temperature of a plant every hour? Or send high-resolution video images 30 times a second?

Comment: I need to send data from laptop to RPI or vice versa. If I can send some dummy data then my next step will be establishing CAN BUS

Comment: You dont generally compile python codes, you interpret them using python interpreter. The aim of high level programming language is to provide syntaxes and functions which are independent of architecture. You use the ``python`` on both rpi and laptop and run the respective codes.

Comment: I ran the codes using python IDE in RPI and spyder on the laptop. But it says "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"